# Custom TableViewSelectionModel not updating

Tags: java, javafx, selectionmodel

I'm trying to write a custom [`TableViewSelectionModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.TableViewSelectionModel.html) to use with my [`TableView`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html) in JavaFX. I've implemented all the abstract methods, and am updating the selected items and selected cells lists. However, the actual selection being shown in the table does not change when I click on another row.

Here is a simplified example, which shows this behavior:

```
import java.util.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView.TableViewSelectionModel;
import javafx.collections.*;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyListWrapper;

public class MySelectionModel<S> extends TableViewSelectionModel<S>{
    Set<Integer> selection = new HashSet<>();
    final ObservableList<TablePosition<S, ?>> selectedCells = FXCollections.<TablePosition<S, ?>>observableArrayList();
    final ObservableList<S> selectedItems = FXCollections.<S>observableArrayList();
    final ObservableList<Integer> selectedIndices = FXCollections.<Integer>observableArrayList();

    public MySelectionModel(TableView<S> tableview){
        super(tableview);
        setCellSelectionEnabled(false);
    }
    public ObservableList<S> getSelectedItems(){
        return new ReadOnlyListWrapper<S>(selectedItems);
    }
    public void clearSelection(int row, TableColumn<S, ?> tableColumn){
        selection.remove(Integer.valueOf(row));
        updateSelection();
    }
    public void clearAndSelect(int row, TableColumn<S, ?> tableColumn){
        selection = Collections.singleton(row);
        updateSelection();
    }
    public void select(int row, TableColumn<S, ?> tableColumn){
        selection.add(Integer.valueOf(row));
        updateSelection();
    }
    public boolean isSelected(int row, TableColumn<S, ?> tableColumn){
        return selection.contains(Integer.valueOf(row));
    }
    public ObservableList<TablePosition> getSelectedCells(){
        return new ReadOnlyListWrapper<TablePosition>((ObservableList<TablePosition>)(Object)selectedCells);
    }
    public ObservableList<Integer> getSelectedIndices(){
        return new ReadOnlyListWrapper<Integer>(selectedIndices);
    }
    public void selectBelowCell(){}
    public void selectAboveCell(){}
    public void selectRightCell(){}
    public void selectLeftCell(){}
    public void updateSelection(){
        List<TablePosition<S, ?>> positions = new ArrayList<>();
        List<S> items = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<>();
        TableView<S> tableView = getTableView();
        for(Integer i : selection){
            positions.add(new TablePosition<S, Object>(tableView, i.intValue(), null));
            items.add(getTableView().getItems().get(i.intValue()));
            indices.add(i);
        }
        selectedCells.setAll(positions);
        selectedItems.setAll(items);
        selectedIndices.setAll(indices);
    }
}
```

Which is being set on the `TableView` like this:

```
TableView<ObservableList<MyData>> table = new TableView<>();
table.setSelectionModel(new MySelectionModel(table));
table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
```

I've confirmed that the new indices are being correctly set by adding `ListChangeListener`s on the two backing `ObservableList`s and displaying the `Change`s. The output is what I'd expect, e.g.

> Selected Cells { [TablePosition [ row: 8, column: null, tableView: TableView@11924c25[styleClass=table-view] ]] replaced by [TablePosition [ row: 12, column: null, tableView: TableView@11924c25[styleClass=table-view] ]] at 0 }
>
> Selected Items { [[MyCustomTableView$Cell@1c988ebb, MyCustomTableView$Cell@6b80b2be]] replaced by [[MyCustomTableView$Cell@4a17d76d, MyCustomTableView$Cell@6e48d6d]] at 0 }

Is there anything I'm missing that would is needed for the `TableView` to update its selection when the `TableViewSelectionModel` changes its selection?

Comment: Are you implementing `getSelectedIndices()`, or modifying that list when the selection changes?

Comment: @James_D I had not been, but I've added it in, and it's still showing the same problem.

Comment: Probably needs a [MCVE]. (I know it's hard to be minimal with a `TableViewSelectionModel` implementation.)

Comment: @James_D I hoped that wouldn't be necessary. Too many methods to keep it short :P I've added the shortest reproducible version I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the method you need to override, in addition to the ones you already have, is

```
public void select(int row) ;
```

which you can implement trivially by delegating to your existing `select` method:

```
@Override
public void select(int row) {
    select(row, null);
}
```

I would also recommend overriding the following:

```
@Override
public void clearAndSelect(int row) {
    clearAndSelect(row, null);
}

@Override
public void selectRange(int start, int end) {
    IntStream.range(start, end).forEach(selection::add);
    updateSelection();
}

@Override
public boolean isSelected(int row) {
    return isSelected(row, null);
}
```

Note also you have one bug. `Collections.singleton(...)` returns an unmodifiable list, so if you select a single row, then try to add items to the selection, you get an `UnsupportedOperationException`. Your `clearAndSelect` needs to be implemented as

```
public void clearAndSelect(int row, TableColumn<S, ?> tableColumn){
    selection.clear();
    selection.add(row);
    updateSelection();
}
```

Comment: Somehow, this works for the example I posted here, but not for my actual code :P. But it should be easy enough to fix now that I have a working example. Thank you for the solution.